# google play application rejected with.. no reason

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I tried 5 times to submit a free quiz game (made with phonegap) to google play.

4 times I got : 
REASON FOR REMOVAL: `Violation of the intellectual property and impersonation or deceptive behavior provisions of the Content Policy`

1 time I got: `Violation of the sexually explicit material provision of the Content Policy. Please refer to the Sex and Nudity policy help article for more information`

- All graphics, icons, developments was made by me. There is no deception inside. Everything is clean and simple. No rude words.
- there is neither sexy text nor images.
- it is a simple free quiz game made with html5/phonegap: 
  http://www.clapquiz.com/mobile/

I am getting crazy with that. I have submited many application (made with AIR with no problem).

Any clue ?

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is about the terms of service of a distribution channel, not programming.

Comment: so you are saying the images of movies are your property?? I think not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because the main pictures are all frames from movies.